# SolidDB SQL stored procedure IF EXISTS syntax error and use Variable in sql statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

EDIT: I figured it's probably not possible to use EXISTS with IF THEN, but I'm stuck on another problem, how to use variable inside sql statement?

```
EXEC SQL EXECDIRECT CREATE CATALOG CATALOG_NAME;
```

Creates catalog with the name 'CATALOG_NAME' instead of what is stored in the variable.
I know in MSSQL you can do this:

```
EXEC('CREATE DATABASE ' + '$(DBNAME)')
```

What is the equivalent in SolidDB sql?

---

I'm am trying to create a soliddb sql stored procedure that takes inputs and execute specific sql statements based on those inputs.My code as follows:

```
"CREATE PROCEDURE ACTION
    (OPTION VARCHAR, CATALOG_NAME VARCHAR)
    BEGIN
        IF OPTION= 'create' THEN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys_catalogs WHERE name=CATALOG_NAME) THEN
                 EXEC SQL EXECDIRECT DROP CATALOG CATALOG_NAME;
            END IF
            EXEC SQL EXECDIRECT CREATE CATALOG CATALOG_NAME;

        ELSEIF OPTION= 'drop' THEN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys_catalogs WHERE name=CATALOG_NAME) THEN
                 EXEC SQL EXECDIRECT DROP CATALOG CATALOG_NAME;
            END IF
        END IF
    END";
```

when I tried execute the script file using

```
solsql -f "C:\solidb.sql" "dba" "dba"
```

I got error:

```
SOLID Procedure Error 23004: Syntax error: syntax error, line 6
```

I tested the code  with the If EXISTS lines commented out, everything else seem to work fine, so I'm sure its the IF EXISTS lines are incorrect.

So my questions are is it possible to do something like what I'm trying to do? If so could you please show me the proper syntax? Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: The logic looks weird: "if exists do_create" + "if exists do_drop" one of them must be wrong. Also there is a typo in `DROP CATALOG CATALOGNAME` --> `DROP CATALOG CATALOG_NAME`

Comment: thanks for noticing the typo, I've fixed that now.
The logic here is to check if the database/catalog to be created already exits, if so drop it first before create it. If catalog to be dropped exists, then drop it, else do nothing.

Comment: I'd start by replacing the asterix by a 1: `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys_catalogs WHERE name=CATALOG_NAME)`. BTW: you did not mention your DBMS platform.

Comment: Its IBM SolidDB v7, I have another question about using the variable in sql statements. 

EXEC SQL EXECDIRECT DROP CATALOG CATALOG_NAME;
This actually creates a catalog of name 'CATALOG_NAME', how do i use the char that is actually stored in the varialbe CATALOG_NAME, thanks.

Comment: changing the asterix to 1 did not work either ={

Answer (score 0):

I think exists can only test if a table exists.
You probably want to use IFNULL
You could set a user variable to null prior to the IFNULL, then have the select set that to 1.